# Can I calculate the similarity of document fields using MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I understand that it is not possible to calculate the Jaccard similarity of two documents using map reduce, since map only takes one item.

I want to calculate the similarity of elements of a document field. Is this possible using map reduce? I cannot see what to emit from my current point.

Input:

```
{'_id': 'foobar1',
 'categories': ['one', 'two', 'three']}
{'_id': 'foobar2',
 'categories': ['one']}
{'_id': 'foobar3',
 'categories': ['one', 'two']}
```

I now want to calculate how similar the categories `one`, `two` and `three` are to each other, considering the documents to which they belong. This could also be states as finding the similarity between the documents in the following set (just in an ideal world, I would not have to recalculate my data to this set).

```
{'_id': 'one'
 'documents': ['foobar1', 'foobar2', 'foobar3']}
{'_id': 'two',
 'categories': ['foobar1', 'foobar3']}
{'_id': 'three',
 'categories': ['foobar1']}
```

Desired output:

```
{('one', 'two'): 2/3,
 ('one', 'three'): 1/3,
 ('two', 'three'): 1/2}
```

Is this possible using map reduce and how?

Up to now I emit from map something like:

```
[{('one', 'two'): 1},
 {('one', 'three'): 1},
 {('two', 'three'): 1},
 {('one', 'two'): 1}]
```

But then of course in reduce I can only calculate the sum, because I do not know what is the union of `S('one')` and `S('three')`.

Will I have to recalculate the sums after map-reduce or can I change my approach to be able to make a similarity between 0 and 1 (like Jaccard does)?

Disclaimer: Even though it might look like university task, it is not. It's for a personal project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can calculate the Jaccard coefficient of two array fields `X` and `Y` using the aggregation framework - which you should always prefer to using map/reduce. The Jaccard coefficient of two sets `X` and `Y` is defined as

```
J(X, Y) = size(X & Y) / size(X | Y)
```

where `size(T)` is the number of elements in the set `T`, `&` is set intersection, and `|` is set union. To compute this using the aggregation framework, use the following (rough) pipeline:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { "intersection" : { "$setIntersection" : ["$X", "$Y"] }, "union" : { "$setUnion" : ["$X", "$Y"] } } },
    { "$project" : { "jaccard" : { "$divide" : [{ "$size" : "$intersection" }, {"$size" : "$union" }] } } }
])
```

I split the calculation into two steps to make it clearer, but it could be one `$project` stage. You may need to add in extra logic to handle cases where both `X` and `Y` are empty or one of them is not an array or is missing. Prepend a `$match` stage to compute coefficients for a subset of the docs.

Comment: Is there a aggregate pipeline keyword for cross product? For `$project` to work with `$X` and `$Y`, the keywords already have to be in the same document (or I misread the docs). So even if I had documents `{"cat1" : [element1, element2], "cat2": [element1, element3]}`, I'd need to do the cross product to get `X = [element1, element2], Y = [element1, element3]` for all cross product possibilities.

Comment: I guess it comes down to describing what exactly you're after. My answer was vaguely directed at the problem but not exactly solving it because it's not clear what you want - could you give the exact output you expect? The desired output you have provided isn't, in any sense I know of, a Jaccard similarity calculation - it's more like computing the frequency of subsets in the field values. Also, if my definition of Jaccard similarity doesn't agree with yours, could you direct me to your source for the definition?

Comment: Your definition of Jaccard similirity is correct, but I think you misunderstood that I do *not* want the similarity of the documents (which I thought was not possible at all), but the Jaccard similarity of the element items. So you could think of "inverting" my documents to '{one: [foobar1, foobar2, foobar3], two: [foobar1, foobar3], three: [foobar1]}' and then taking the jaccard similarity of the documents here. But a solution for jaccard similarity between documents is fine, too. From your answer, I just guess, that I can only do jaccard similarity for *two fields in one document*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. With the given document structure, I think the best way to calculate that information would be most clientside, by retrieving a set of ids of docs containing `one` and `two` and then computing the Jaccard similarity of those sets. Map/reduce and aggregation won't be able to manipulate the documents to "invert" them w.r.t. to the field values, as you nicely put it.